# Snap package only runs when root

Tags: snap, pycharm

I installed the snap package `pycharm-community` using `snap` (while being logged into my Ubuntu One account). When I run `snap list` I can see the package in the list. However, I can only run this app when I run `sudo pycharm-community`. Without root access, I get a `pycharm-community: command not found` error.

How do I run pycharm without `sudo`?

**EDIT**: output of `snap version`:

```
$ snap version
snap       2.29.4.2
snapd      2.29.4.2
series     16
linuxmint  18.3
kernel     4.13.0-21-generic
```

Comment: As your normal user, what happens if you `snap run pycharm-community` and `/snap/bin/pycharm-community`, and what if you launch it from the menu/dash?

Comment: `snap run pycharm-community` runs as a normal user, `/snap/bin/pycharm-community` does not exist, nor is there any launcher in the menu

Comment: What's the output of `snap version` please?

Comment: Output of `snap version` added to the post

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd /home

$ sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic

$ pycharm-community
Jan 02, 2018 12:17:45 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
Jan 02, 2018 12:17:45 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 run
```

I used `cd /home` then `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`
then just type `python-community` and it worked.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Instead, copy the text, paste it into your answer, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Done.
Input stands for what i input in the shell and output stands for what the shell has returned